# javascript object of NFL Schedule

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to build out an object that contains the NFL's 2012 schedule. I found a CSV of it online and can parse through it ok except for when I am trying to add games to each week. When I console log the schedule after the code executes each week only get one game (the last one) instead of the 16 (or so, depending on byes) they should have.

Note: Normally I put my prototypes in a source file instead of here but for clarity I included them.

BONUS: I'll post the object when it is complete. : D

Here's my code:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}

String.prototype.capitalize = function() { 
    return this.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.substr(1);
}

Object.prototype.getKeys = function(obj){
    var keys = [];
    for(var key in obj){
        keys.push(key);
    }
    return keys;
}

Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (this[i] == obj) {
            return true;
        }
   }
   return false;
}

var AppController = {};

//create a schedule object
AppController.Schedule = {};
var schedule = AppController.Schedule;

    var scheduleArray = nflschedule.split(":::");

    //set a game count so we can give each game an id
    var gameCount = -1;

    for(var i=0; i<scheduleArray.length; i++) { 

        gameCount++;

        //filter out first line
        if (i>0) { 

            //get a game
            var thisGameItems = scheduleArray[i].split(",");

            //game date
            var gameDate = thisGameItems[0];

            //week number
            var colonSplitPattern = new RegExp("^[^:]+(?=:)");
            var weekNumPattern=new RegExp("\Week(.*)");
            var weekNum = "Week" + thisGameItems[2].match(colonSplitPattern).toString().match(weekNumPattern)[1].trim();
            //get teams and game day
            var homeTeam = thisGameItems[thisGameItems.length-3].trim();
            var visitingTeam = thisGameItems[thisGameItems.length-2].trim();
            var weekDay =   thisGameItems[thisGameItems.length-1].trim().capitalize();

            //check Schedule and see if we have this weekNum as key, if not add it
            var gameWeeks = schedule.getKeys();
            if (gameWeeks.contains(weekNum) == false) { 
                schedule[weekNum] = {};
            }

            var thisWeeksGames = schedule[weekNum];
            //add games to the game week
            thisWeeksGames[gameCount] = {

                GameDate: gameDate,
                GameWeek: weekNum,
                HomeTeam: homeTeam,
                VisitingTeam: visitingTeam,
                GameDay: weekDay,
                HomeTeamScore : "",
                VistingTeamScore : ""

            }

        }
    }

console.log(schedule);
```

Comment: Did you `console.log(weekNum)` in the loop?

Comment: Edit: Week num totals out at 17, gameCount at 256, 17 is the number of weeks of football and 256 is the number of games that will be played this season.

Comment: When I console.log schedule I get this Object { Week1={...}, Week2={...}, Week3={...}, more...}, as expected. When I console.log schedule['Week1'] I get this: Object { 16={...}, getKeys=function()}....all the data fir game 16 of week 1 is there and accurate but games 1-15 are not.

Comment: Just to add some more to this: if I console.log(schedule[weekNum][gameCount]) right after the thisWeeksGames[gameCount] = {
... code it logs correctly, I can see every game, but if I console log outside the loop then each week only shows 1 game. Grrrr. What am I missing?

Comment: It is very hard to tell the best solution without being able to see the data structure, but if you want to add several games per week-object, then you need a nested loop. I assume right now you're simply overwriting previously stored data.

Comment: I'd post the datasource but it's huge. I figured I was over writing something but I can't see where it's happening.

Comment: Can't you just post a part of it so we can see the structure?